# Data from controller not going to view (PHP Codeigniter)

Tags: php, codeigniter, model-view-controller

I'm trying to get the $data from my controller to go into my view but it does not seem to be working. I keep getting a "variable does not exist" error. Here's the Controller code (view is loaded in a different part).

```
            $affiliate_id = $this->input->get_post('affiliate_id');
        $product_id = $this->input->get_post('product_id');
        $data = array();

        if (empty($affiliate_id)
            && empty($product_id))
        {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('error', 'Please enter an affiliate ID, a product ID, or both.');
            redirect('admin/affiliate_relationship');
        }

        if (empty($affiliate_id))
        {
            $data['affiliate_relationship'] = $this->AffiliateRelationship->search_for_affiliate_by_product_id($product_id);
        }
        elseif (empty($product_id))
        {
            $data['affiliate_relationship'] = $this->AffiliateRelationship->search_for_affiliate_by_affiliate_id($affiliate_id);
            $affiliate = $affiliate_id;
        }
        elseif (!empty($affiliate_id)
                && !empty($product_id))
        {
            $data['affiliate_relationship'] = $this->AffiliateRelationship->search_for_affiliate($affiliate_id, $product_id);
            $affiliate = $affiliate_id . '/';
        }

        $data['affiliate_id'] = $affiliate_id;
        $data['product_id'] = $product_id;

        redirect_and_continue_processing('admin/affiliate_relationship/' . $affiliate . $product_id, $data);
```

When I pr($data) I get the array correctly, so I know the data is all there. It's just when it is used in the view it does not even exist.

Am I doing something wrong? I've done other controller and views more-or-less the same way and never got problem this before.

EDIT: View code.

```
<?php
$affiliateRelationshipRows = NULL;

if (!empty($affiliate_relationship))
{
$class = NULL;
$i = 0;

foreach ($affiliate_relationship->result_array() as $affiliate)
{
    if (++$i%2 == 0)
    {
        $class= ' class="odd"';
    }
    else
    {
        $class = NULL;
    }

    $affiliateRelationshipRows .= <<<END
    <tr $class>
        <td class="text-left">{$affiliate['id']}</td>
        <td class="text-left">{$affiliate['product_id']}</td>
        <td class="text-left">{$affiliate['user_id']}</td>
        <td class="text-left">{$affiliate['affiliate_status_id']}</td>
        <td class="text-left">{$affiliate['created']}</tD>
        <td class="text-left">{$affiliate['custom_payout']}</td>
        <td class="text-left">{$affiliate['delayed']}</td>
        <td class="text-left">{$affiliate['sales_page_url']}</td>
        <td class="text-left">{$affiliate['comments']}</td>
    </tr>
END;
}
}
?>

<?php echo form_open($this->uri->uri_string()); ?>

<div class="box-search">
<div class="grid-2" style="width:200px; margin-left:25px;">
    <span class="label" style="float:none;">
        Affiliate ID:
    </span>
    <span class="field" style="float:none;">
        <input type="text" name="affiliate_id" value="<?php if (!empty($affiliate_id)) { echo $affiliate_id; } ?>" style="width: 75px;"/>
    </span>
    <?php echo form_error('affiliate_id'); ?>
</div>

<div class="grid-2" style="width:200px; margin-left:0px;">
    <span class="label" style="float:none; ">
        Product ID:
    </span>
    <span class="field" style="float:none;">
        <input type="text" name="product_id" value="<?php if (!empty($product_id)) { echo $product_id; } ?>" style="width:75px;"/>
    </span>
    <?php echo form_error('product_id'); ?>
</div>

<a href="/admin/affiliate_relationship" class="btn btn-mini-submit btn-blue btn-search" style="margin-right: 100px;">RESET</a>
<input type="submit" name="search" class="btn btn-green btn-mini-submit btn-search" value="SEARCH"/>
<div class="clear"></div>
</div>

<?php echo form_close(); ?>

<div class="box">
<div class="top">
    Affiliate Relationship
</div>
<div class="main-table">
    <table class="style1" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" width="100%" border="0">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Product ID</th>
                <th>User ID</th>
                <th>Affiliate Status ID</th>
                <th>Created</th>
                <th>Custom Payout</th>
                <th>Delayed</th>
                <th>Sales Page URL</th>
                <th>Comments</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <?php echo $affiliateRelationshipRows; ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

The array:

```
Array
(
[affiliate_relationship] => Array
    (
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [id] => 11615304
                [created] => 2015-09-17 00:00:00
                [product_id] => 175538
                [user_id] => 393598
                [comments] => 
                [affiliate_status_id] => 2
                [custom_payout] => 
                [delayed] => 0
                [sales_page_url] => 
            )

    )

[affiliate_id] => 11615304
[product_id] => 175538
)
```

Comment: in your view try this--> echo $affiliate_id;

Comment: How did you try to retrieve the data in your view ? can you display the view code ?

Comment: Echoing gives me the same error, unidentified variable.

Comment: Please print the array inside <pre> tag and and send the result

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can send data like that in redirect_and_continue_processing() or redirect() in codeigniter. The only way to do that is by sending the data as an argument to the function that you are trying to redirect to. Then in that function, use the data to generate the view.

LIke :

```
 redirect_and_continue_processing('admin/affiliate_relationship/' . $affiliate . $product_id/$data);
```

And in the method "affiliate_relationship" , accept the argument

Redirect method does not take an argument as the variable to send to view.

Answer (score -1):

instead of using 
 redirect_and_continue_processing('admin/affiliate_relationship/' . $affiliate . $product_id, $data);

you can use simple way to do this

$this->load->view('your_view_name','your data in array');